# Angular iterate an array with two conditions

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, rxjs, lodash

I have this array and these values:

```
levels$: Observable<any[]> = [
    {
       name: 'first level primary school'     
    }, 
    {
       name: 'second level primary school'     
    },
    {
      name: 'first level secondary school'     
    }
]

const isPrimarySchool = false
const isSecondarySchool = false
```

And I want to iterate the array and find if there is a string with the word 'primary' or 'secondary' (it could be both), and turn the value of isPrimarySchool or isSecondarySchool to true, or both if it's the case.

The method that I found to resolve this, is this one:

```
this.levels$.subscribe(levels =>
      levels.forEach(level => {
        if (level.name.toLowerCase().includes('primary') {
          this.isPrimarySchool = true
        }
        if (level.name.toLowerCase().includes('secondary')) {
          this.isSecondarySchool = true
        }
      })
    )
```

Is there a better way to resolve the two 'if' parts, using lodash or normal javascript?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
this.levels$.subscribe(levels =>{
this.isPrimarySchool =levels.some(level => level.name.toLowerCase().includes('primary'));
this.isSecondarySchool = levels.some(level => level.name.toLowerCase().includes('secondary'));
    })
```

Comment: btw you can make a function for this => ```levels.some(level => level.name.toLowerCase().includes('secondary') ``` therefore you wouldn't duplicate your code

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to use find here, since we only need one instance of primary/secondary occurring in order to determine the values?

Answer (score 0):

You could use If/Else instead of 2 Ifs, and use a 3rd else.

Remember that using If/elsif/else will be less costly than adding 2 If's.

Or, you could ternary operators but that's most likely not a better approach.

Comment: In my opinion, if else  is not a good solution here because for the example data both isPrimarySchool and isSecondarySchool can be true

Comment: That may be true, but my opinion is that using multiple IF statements makes it compulsory to check all conditions, while using if elsif if would only need one statement to be true, so first check would be for isPrimarySchool  & isSecondarySchool, second for isPrimarySchool  and last for isSecondarySchool.